# When are integral operators trace class?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-transforms

Define an integral operator $T$ on $L^2([0,1])$ by $$Tf(x) = \int_0^1 K(x, y) f(y) \, dy. $$ Such an operator is Hilbert-Schmidt when $K$ is in $L^2([0,1]\times [0,1])$.

I heard that if $K$ is smooth, then $T$ is in fact trace-class. Why is this?

When is such an operator trace-class?

Comment: This is a compact set so $K$ continuous should already be enough

Comment: You can bound the trace norm by $\|T\|_1 \le \sup_{x,y} |K(x,y)|$

Comment: Sorry if this is easy, but how? It seems awkward to work with a basis.

Comment: It's because$|Te_k| \le (\sup_{x,y} |K(x,y)|) |e_k|$ for any function $e_k$. So it doesn't matter so much which orthonormal basis you take. A concrete basis would be $e_k(x) = e^{2\pi i k x}$ suitably normalized

Comment: @user404188: I'm interested in how that argument goes. The only way to tell if $T$ is trace-class by using a single basis, is to have an expression for $(T^*T)^{1/2}$, which I doubt can be written explicitly in terms of $K$.

Comment: @user404188, I realize that this is quite late but I am wondering if you could briefly lay out a sketch of a proof of the statement you made within your second comment. I realize that this is true for the operator norm, however I am no convinced that it is true under the prescribed conditions for the trace norm.  Are you using one of the variational definitions of the trace distance? If so which one and what are your sources, I want to use such a resutl as the one you have presented but I am having a hard time proving it. Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a treatment of this result in the book 'Functional Analysis' by Lax.

Note that $ T^{*}T $ also has a smooth kernel,
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{K}(x,y)=\int \bar{K}(z,x) K(z,y)\, dz,
\end{equation*}
and that the min-max principle ensures that the non-increasing sequence of eigenvalues of $T^{*} T$, $\lambda_1 \geqslant \lambda_2 \geqslant \ldots$, are given by
\begin{equation*}
  \lambda_{n} = \min_{\substack{\mathcal V \subseteq \mathcal H \\ \dim \mathcal V = n-1}} \max_{x\in \mathcal V^{\perp}} \, \langle x, T^{*} T x\rangle.
\end{equation*}
Thus, if $\mathcal V _{n}$ denotes the subspace of polynomials of degree $\leqslant n-2$, then we have
\begin{equation*}
  \lambda_{n} \leqslant \max_{x \in \mathcal V_{n} ^{\perp}} \, \langle x, T^{*} T x\rangle = \max_{x \in \mathcal V_{n} ^{\perp}} \, \langle x, (T^{*} T - L_{p_{n-2}}) x\rangle \leqslant \lVert \tilde{K} - p_{n-2}\rVert_{\infty} \rightarrow 0,
\end{equation*}
where $L_{p_{n-2}}$ denotes an integral operator whose kernel
$$
p_{n-2}(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}c_{ij}x^i y^j
$$
is a polynomial of degree at most $n-2$ in each separate variable, and the sequence $(p_{n})_{n\geqslant 0}$ is a sequence chosen by means of the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem such that $\lVert \tilde{K} - p_{n-2}\rVert_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$. We conclude that $T^{*} T$ is compact, which implies that $T$ is compact. In order to show that $T$ is trace class, we must refine the argument in such a way that
\begin{equation}
  \tag{1}
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\lambda_{n}} < \infty,
\end{equation}
i.e. we need to pick polynomials which approximate $K$ sufficiently well.

First, a reminder concerning Bernstein polynomials. Given a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, introduce the Bernstein polynomial of degree $n$,
\begin{equation*}
  p_{n}(t)=\sum_{m=0}^{n} f\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) \binom{n}{m} t^{m}(1-t)^{n-m}.
\end{equation*}
Then we have $p_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly. In fact, if we pick iid Bernoulli distributed variables $X_{1}^{(t)},X_{2}^{(t)},\ldots$, with $X_{j}^{(t)}\sim \text{Bernoulli}(t)$ and define $S_{n}^{(t)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n} X_{m}^{(t)}$ then we have
\begin{equation*}
  p_{n}(t)=E f\left(S_{n}^{(t)} \right),
\end{equation*}
since $nS_{n}^{(t)} \sim \text{Binomial}(n,t)$. Furthermore, since $f$ is uniformly continuous, given $\epsilon>0$, we may pick $\delta>0$ such that if $\lvert f(t) - f(x) \rvert > \epsilon / 2 $, then $\lvert t - x \rvert > \delta$. It now follows from Chebyshev's inequality that
\begin{equation*}
  P(\lvert f(S_{n}^{(t)}) - f(t) \rvert\geqslant \epsilon / 2 ) \leqslant P(\lvert S_{n}^{(t)} - t \rvert\geqslant \delta)  \leqslant \frac{t(1-t)}{\delta^{2}n}.
\end{equation*}
Thus, since $t(1-1)\leqslant 1/4$, we find if $n>\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}/ \epsilon \delta ^{2}$ that
\begin{equation*}
  \lvert p_{n}(t) - f(t) \rvert \leqslant E\lvert f(S_{n}^{(t)}) - f(t) \rvert \leqslant \epsilon/2 + \frac{\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}}{2\delta^{2}n}<\epsilon,
\end{equation*}
which concludes the proof that $p_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly.

We now extend the construction to two variables, so that it may be applied to obtain an approximation of $K$. For $n\in \mathbb{N}_{0}$, define
\begin{align*}
  p_{n}(t_{1},t_{2})&=E f(S_{1,n}^{(t_{1})},S_{2,n}^{(t_{2})}) \\
&= \sum_{m_1=0}^{n} \sum_{m_2=0}^{n} f\left(\frac{m_1}{n},\frac{m_2}{n}\right) \binom{n}{m_1} \binom{n}{m_2} t_1^{m_1}(1-t_1)^{n-m_1} t_2^{m_2}(1-t_2)^{n-m_2},
\end{align*}
where $S_{1,n}^{(t)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}X_{1,m}^{(t_{1})},S_{1,n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}X_{2,m}^{(t_{2})}$ and $X_{1,m}^{(t_{1})},X_{2,m}^{(t_{2})}$ are iid with $\text{Bernoulli}(t_{1}),\text{Bernoulli}(t_{2})$ distribution. As before, given $\epsilon>0$, we pick $\delta>0$ such that if $\lvert f(t) - f(x) \rvert > \epsilon / 2 $, then $\lvert t - x \rvert > \delta$. Putting $t=(t_{1},t_{2})$ and $S_{n}^{(t)} = (S_{n}^{(t_{1})},S_{n}^{(t_{2})})$, we find similarly to before that
\begin{align*}
  &P(\lvert f(S_{n}^{(t)}) - f(t) \rvert\geqslant \epsilon / 2 ) \leqslant P(\lvert S_{n}^{(t)} - t \rvert\geqslant \delta) \\
  &\qquad \leqslant P(\lvert S_{1,n}^{(t_{1})} - t_{1} \rvert\geqslant \delta/2) + P(\lvert S_{2,n}^{(t_{2})} - t_{2} \rvert\geqslant \delta/2) \\
  &\qquad \leqslant \frac{4 t_{1}(1-t_{1})}{\delta^{2}n} + \frac{4 t_{2}(1-t_{2})}{\delta^{2}n} \leqslant \frac{6}{\delta^{2}n}.
\end{align*}
Thus, we find if $n> 32 \lVert f \rVert_{\infty}/ \epsilon \delta ^{2}$ that
\begin{equation*}
  \lvert p_{n}(t) - f(t) \rvert \leqslant E\lvert f(S_{n}^{(t)}) - f(t) \rvert \leqslant \epsilon/2 + \frac{16 \lVert f \rVert_{\infty}}{\delta^{2}n}<\epsilon,
\end{equation*}
which concludes the proof that $p_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly in this case.

At this point we have an explicit construction of an approximating sequence of polynomials $(p_{n})_{n\geqslant 0}$ at hand. In order to obtain (1), we refine this choice of approximating sequence. Recall the fifth order Taylor formula with remainder, namely
\begin{align*}
  f(t)&=\sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert\leqslant 5} \, \partial^{\alpha}\! f(x)(t-x)^{\alpha}/\alpha! \\
  &\qquad + 6 \sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert = 6} \int_{0}^{1}(1-s)^{5}\,\partial^{\alpha}\! f(ts+(1-t)x)(t-x)^{\alpha}/\alpha! \,ds.
\end{align*}
This suggests that we consider the refined sequence
\begin{equation*}
  q_{n+5}(t) = \sum_{ \lvert \alpha \rvert \leqslant 5 } E \, \partial ^{\alpha}\!f (S_{n}^{(t)}) (t-S_{n}^{(t)}) ^{\alpha} /  \alpha!.
\end{equation*}
Note that $q_{n+5}$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n+5$ in $t_1$ or $t_2$. This time around, we find
\begin{equation*}
  \lvert q_{n+5}(t) - f(t) \rvert \leqslant   \lVert \sum_{\lvert\alpha\rvert = 6} \, \partial^{\alpha}\! f/\alpha! \rVert_{\infty} \,E\,\lvert S_{n}^{(t)} - t\rvert^{6}.
\end{equation*}
By Minkowski's inequality, we have
\begin{equation*}
  (E\,\lvert S_{n}^{(t)} - t\rvert^{6})^{1/6} \leqslant (E\,\lvert S_{1,n}^{(t_{1})} - t_{1}\rvert^{6})^{1/6} + (E\,\lvert S_{n}^{(t_{2})} - t_{2}\rvert^{6})^{1/6},
\end{equation*}
and one can show that
\begin{equation*}
E\,\lvert S_{1,n}^{(t_{1})} - t_{1}\rvert^{6} \leqslant \frac{C}{n^{3}}
\end{equation*}
for some constant $C>0$. This leads to the bound
\begin{equation*}
  E\,\lvert S_{n}^{(t)} - t\rvert^{6} \leqslant \frac{C'}{(n+7)^{3}}
\end{equation*}
for another constant $C'>0$. All in all, we find
\begin{equation*}
  \lvert q_{n}(t) - f(t) \rvert \leqslant C''/(n+2)^{3},
\end{equation*}
and therefore $\lambda_{n} \leqslant C''/n^{3}$, which suffices to ensure that (1) holds.